# Angular serve a file and use it as a source for searchable dropdown list

Tags: angular, dspace

It's DSpace Angular project.
I modify the submission form.
There is a field in the form that it's to be filled by a list of words in XML format containing more than 6000 words.

So ideally, it could be like Excel searchable dropdown list to filter a column of words, then the user can select one or multiple words from the list. (If it could match semantic meaning of the word, it would be the bonus. )

Please advice.

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with the implementation? What have you tried so far. Unfortunately SO is not a platform to search for freelancers writing code for you.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus, I am looking for some advice on which kinds of functions I need to develop, not necessary writing code for me.

Comment: I've implemented DSpace in my local machine.  And customized the submission form. https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/main/dspace/config/item-submission.xml